# socketio freezes after 3k connexions

Tags: socket.io

I have a basic **socketio server** like :

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');

var server = express();
var serverApp = server.listen(3000);
io = io.listen(serverApp);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
});
```

And a basic **client** node :

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');

function startTest() {
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', {forceNew: true});

    socket.on('disconnect', function (err) {
        startTest();
    });

    socket.on('connect', function () {
        nbConnexions++;
        console.log('connected, nbConnexions : ' + nbConnexions);

        socket.disconnect();
    });
}


startTest();
```

After ~3k connexions the server freezes, and continues after 1 minut, and freezes again after 3k more, and again ...

Problem may come from socketio ? Have you got the same "bug" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i found

After the 3k connexions, i have same value for

```
sysctl net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_count
```

and

```
sysctl net.nf_conntrack_max
```

Increasing the value in /proc/sys/net/nf_conntrack_max to 65535, problem solved !

Answer (score 0):

I have no memory leaks. Socketio just no responses. If i restart the server just after the 3k connexions and freeze, it always waits 1 minut before connect with new request.

I'm on debian version 7.6, with socketio 1.2.1
I haven't the problem with same code on windows.

Does Linux block some resource/port avec 3k sockets ?